# prove that if $k|m$, $\mathbb{Z}_m$ has a subgroup of order $k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

prove that if $k|m$, then $\mathbb{Z}_m$ has a subgroup of order $k$. 
im not sure where to start with this.  any help is appreciated.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Take the element $m/k$ in $\mathbb{Z_m}$. What's its order?

Answer (score 1):

Useful hint:

If $\mathbb Z_m=\langle a\rangle$ which means that $|a|=m$, then $|a^t|=\frac{m}{\gcd(t,m)}$. According to the condition of the problem $\gcd(\frac{m}{k},m)=\frac{m}{k}$ since $k\mid m$ so $H=\langle a^{\frac{m}{k}}\rangle$ would be the desire subgroup.